# Spring Security REST CORS withCredentials A wildcard '*'

Tags: jquery, spring-security, cross-domain, spring-boot

I'm trying to set up a Spring Boot application using Spring Security and exposing REST services.

I added the CORS filter suggested here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/
But it's not enough it seems.

Code:

```
@Component
public class CrossOriginRequestFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with, Authorization");
        chain.doFilter(req, response);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

The jQuery request looks like this:

```
var bytes = btoa("admin" + ":" + "admin");

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: '[url removed]',
headers: {"Authorization": "Basic " + bytes},
xhrFields: {
    withCredentials: true
},
success: function(a,b,c) {
console.log(a);
console.log(b);
console.log(c);
},
error: function (e1,e2,e3) {
console.log(e1);
console.log(e2);
console.log(e3);
}
});
```

I'm getting this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load [url omitted]. A wildcard '*' cannot be used in the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header when the credentials flag is true. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

P.S: I'm accessing the remote server from localhost:8080, guess that's why it says so in the Origin.

Anyone know what I'm missing?
Saw some code here at Stack where people checked if it was a OPTIONS request, but I don't find the ServletRequest.getMethod, and besides, it seems a bit hacky?

Comment: Are you using tomcat for deployment?

Comment: Jetty 8, from Spring Boot

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at the last release Spring Boot 1.3.M1:
https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/12/spring-boot-1-3-0-m1-available-now

> The recently released Spring Framework 4.2 RC1 provides first class support for CORS out-of-the-box, giving you an easier and more powerful way to configure it than typical filter based solutions.

```
@CrossOrigin(maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @CrossOrigin(origin = "http://domain2.com")
    @RequestMapping("/{id}")
    public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
```

... and more: https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework

Comment: Spring Framework CORS builtin support handles this use case. It allows you to configure a `*` allowed origin, and when credentials are needed like in the question, it will use the domain provided in the `Origin` header for the request to set the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response header value.